# "Search" not working with while loop - Library System

Tags: python, while-loop

In the code below the problem is:
If the entered book is searched, and if it is availible in .txt file, then code works fine (I am not sure if the code I used can be refined as well).

But when the wrong name is entered in search and the programme enteres in while search is not in a, then I want to repeat search option from the top until the right number is entered.

```
`search=input('enter the number or name of the book you want to search\n')
i=1
books=True
with open('books.txt') as f:
    a=f.read()
with open('books.txt') as f:
    while books:
            books=f.readline()
            if search in books:
                    print(books+' Availible')
                    av1=True
                    b1=books
            i+=1
    while search not in a:
     search=(input('This Book is currently unavailible,enter new book\n'))
```

`

Comment: Why do you read the book-file twice?

Comment: `with open('books.txt') as f:  books = f.readlines()` gives you a list of lines. search the list instead of opening the file again

Answer (score 0):

Don't read the file twice, and no need of you look inside, just search in the whole content as one string

```
with open('books.txt') as f:
    all_books = f.read()

search = input('Enter the number or name of the book you want to search: ')
while search not in all_books:
    search = input('This Book is currently unavailable, enter new book: ')

print(search, "is available")
```

That would match any substring in the file, including half book name, to match only full lines

```
with open('data.txt') as f:
    all_books = f.read().splitlines()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Add a while loop to repeat what you want like this

```
search=input('enter the number or name of the book you want to search\n')

while True:
    i=1
    books=True
    with open('books.txt') as f:
        a=f.read()
    with open('books.txt') as f:
        while books:
            books=f.readline()
            if search in books:
                print(books+' Availible')
                av1=True
                b1=books
                i+=1
        if search not in a:
            print('This Book is currently unavailible.')
            search=input(enter the number or name of the book you want to search\n')
```